# How to perform MySQL UPSERT

Tags: php, mysql, upsert

This is how my table looks like.

```
CREATE TABLE `answers` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`basicinfo_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`question_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`answer` INT(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `question_id` (`question_id`),
INDEX `basicinfo_id` (`basicinfo_id`),
CONSTRAINT `basicinfo_id` FOREIGN KEY (`basicinfo_id`) REFERENCES `basic_info` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `question_id` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `questions` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION) COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3383;
```

This is how the data can look like

[image]

I want to update the answers if they already exist for "basicinfo_id". 
OR
If I change the answer for question_id 1, 2 and 3. How can i upsert the data.?

I have tried this query but it doesn't update the result.

```
INSERT INTO answers (basicinfo_id, question_id, answer) VALUES('98', 1, '1'),('98', 2, '1'),('98', 3, '1'),('98', 4, '1'),('98', 5, '1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE basicinfo_id = 98;
```

I have defined a composite unique key now and this is how it looks like but it still didn't work.

```
CREATE TABLE `answers` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`basicinfo_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`question_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`answer` INT(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE INDEX `basicinfo_id_question_id` (`basicinfo_id`, `question_id`),
INDEX `question_id` (`question_id`),
INDEX `basicinfo_id` (`basicinfo_id`),
CONSTRAINT `basicinfo_id` FOREIGN KEY (`basicinfo_id`) REFERENCES `basic_info` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `question_id` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `questions` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION ) COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3718;
```

Comment: the upsert will never occur. you never cause a duplicate key violation. only when there is a unique key violation will the "on duplicate key" stuff actually trigger. no key violation, no update.

Comment: I am sorry if am coming a bit ignorant here, but if i set basicinfo_id as UNIQUE it will not allowed duplicate basicinfo_id which i don't want but if i set basicinfo_id and question_id both as composite unique key then it is possible. Do i make any sense?

Comment: yes, you'd need a composite unique key in this case.

Comment: I tried the same query after making composite unique key but it still didn't update it. I am adding the table schema to the question. I will appreciate if you can have a look.

Comment: well, you're inserting a bunch of records with `id=98`, but the only update that field, with the EXACT SAME value. so... the upsert literally has no point, since you replace a value with itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE basicinfo_id = 98;` is malformed

Try this :
`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 'answer' = VALUES('answer');`

If a unique key already exists it will update the `answer` field